# how to use UINavigationController for open personal cocoaTouchFramework

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I want to make a CocoaTouchFramework and use it in other projects.
it's the first time that I make a framework and I don't know how to open this framework with UINavigationController.
I can open and use them by the present method but I get an error when I push UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

You must open it from UINavigationController instance. For example:

```swift
let frameworkViewController = FrameworkViewController()
navigationController?.pushViewController(frameworkViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: its my code for present to framework .


        let frameworkBundle = Bundle(identifier: "raadco.Masoud")

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "masoud", bundle: frameworkBundle)

        let mas = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginForm") as! loginForm
        
        present(mas, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Is the `loginForm` contain `UINavigationController` inside the storyboard? If yes, you can't push `loginForm` from navigation controller. You need to remove the navigation controller and just left UIViewController instance only.